# Heart-beating in STOMP client

Tags: java, activemq-classic, socketexception, stomp

The design of my current stomp client process is as follows:

1. Open stomp connection (sending CONNECT frame)
2. Subscribe to a feed (send a SUBSCRIBE frame)
3. Do a loop to continually receive feed:

> ```
> while (true) {
>                 connection.begin("txt1");
>
>                     StompFrame message = connection.receive();
>                     System.out.println("message get header"+message.toString());
>                     LOG.info(message.getBody());
>
>                     connection.ack(message, "txt1");
>
>                 connection.commit("txt1");
>
>             }
> ```

My problem with this process is that I get

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)...
```

and I think the cause of this is mostly because the feed I am subscribed to gives information slower on certain times (as I normally get this error when the weekend comes, holidays or evenings).

I have been reading up on this [here](http://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.1.html#Heart-beating) and I think this would help with my problem. However, I'm not so sure how to incorporate it with the current layout of my stomp client. Would I have to send a CONNECT header within Step 3?

I am currently using activemq to create my stomp client if that helps.

In the stomp [spec](http://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.1.html#Heart-beating) we have:

> Regarding the heart-beats themselves, any new data received over the
>   network connection is an indication that the remote end is alive. In a
>   given direction, if heart-beats are expected every  milliseconds:
>
> - the sender MUST send new data over the network connection at least    every  milliseconds
> - if the sender has no real STOMP frame to send,    it MUST send a single newline byte (0x0A)
> - if, inside a time window of    at least  milliseconds, the receiver did not receive any new data,    it CAN consider the
>     connection as dead
> - because of timing    inaccuracies, the receiver SHOULD be tolerant and take into account    an error margin

Would that mean my client would need to send a newline bye every n seconds?

Comment: I agree that you would see "Read timed out" exceptions due inactivity on connection. You can fix this by using heartbeats feature provided in STOMP 1.1 spec. Which STOMP client library are you using? See http://stomp.github.io/implementations.html#STOMP_Clients and choose the one which supports STOMP 1.1, and you will have API methods to enable heartbeats.

Comment: Hi @Buchi, thank you for you reply. I am using activemq as my STOMP client library and using [this](https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/trunk/activemq-stomp/src/test/java/org/apache/activemq/transport/stomp/StompTest.java) as my reference. At the moment I send `heart-beat 0,2000` in the header for step 1 (see above) but I don't know exactly where to go from there

Comment: I don't see any heartbeat related code in the test program that you pointed. However, I see some heart-beat related constants in Stomp.java class. You should actually check if the library is sending periodic heartbeats to broker, otherwise, you will have to add it yourself. My guess is ActiveMQ Java STOMP library isn't kind of up-to-date and I don't think it implements STOMP 1.1 also. You can look for alternative Java STOMP libraries and experiment with them. For example, see https://github.com/mrstampy/Stampy

Comment: I will do. Thanky you for reply @Buchi :)

Comment: it is still not clear to me how heart-beating works. If I send `CONNECT
heart-beat:0,1000
client-id:<client-id>
passcode:<passcode>
login:<login>` I get a reply `CONNECTED
heart-beat:1000,0
version:1.0
session:<login>
server:ActiveMQ/5.8.0` I dont see how I could listen to the heart beat if i only do this on connect...

Answer (score 6):

The stomp server you are connected to has timed out your connection due to innactivity.

Providing the server supports Stomp version 1.1 or newer, the easiest solution for your client is to include a heart-beat instruction in the header of your CONNECT, such as "0,10000".  This tells the server that you cannot send heart-beats, but you want it to send one every 10 seconds.  This way you don't need to implement them, and the server will keep the connection active by sending them to you.

Of course the server will have its own requirements of the client.  In your comment it responds to your request with "1000,0".  This indicates that it will send a heart-beat every 1000 millisecs, and it expects you to send one every 0 millisecs, 0 indicating none at all.  So your job will be minimal.

Comment: Hi Robert, does this mean that the client does not have to do anything (such as responding to server’s heartbeats) to keep a connection active when the client connect with “0,10000” ?

Comment: @Tim If the server responds with a requirement that the client send heatbeats, then the client will need to do that.  This would depend on which server is being used and how it is configured.  By default it would not require the client to send heartbeats, so the client does not have to do anything